# How to set defaultValue in ProFormSelect component in ant design pro?

Tags: antd, stack-overflow, default-value, ant-design-pro

I am new to ant design pro and when i tried to set default value through defaultValue in ProFormSelect component (like we do in Select component) nothing happens. Correct answers will be appriciated.

In the status form field there are multiple options like active, inactive,  disabled and i want to set active as default value in that field. i have tried may ways but it did not work. i have reseach everywhere but could not find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I find out initialValue in ant design works same as the defaultValue in ant design.

Comment: You can supporting links or snippet to help the OP.

Comment: You can supporting links or snippet to help the OP.